# How do I iterate through to end of file

Tags: python

I want the following code to read this existing text file.

`["Jenny", "Carlos", "Matty", "Anna"]`

How do I do write some good to get this output.

`["0 Jenny", "1 Carlos", "2 Matty", "3 Anna"]`

This is what I have so far...

```
champions = []
n = 0
winners = open("victory.txt","r")
while True:
    champions[n] = winners.readline()
    n = n + 1
print(champions)
```

Comment: The existing file is of one line or multiple lines?

Comment: the existing text file contains LITERALLY `["Jenny", "Carlos", "Matty", "Anna"]`, or does it contain `Jenny Carlos Matty Anna`, because those are two way different things to consider

Comment: The existing file with contain the names, I just want to append it so it adds the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
champions = [champion.strip() for champion in open("victory.txt")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option to solve your Problem:

```
i = 0
with (open('myFile.txt', 'r')) as data:
    for line in data:
        print str(i) + ' ' + line.rstrip()
        i += 1
```

Explanation:

```
i = 0
```

Initializing our counter for the rowcount

```
with (open('myFile.txt', 'r')) as data:
```

Open our file in read mode an put each in an array called 'data'.

```
for line in data:
    print str(i) + ' ' + line.rstrip()
    i += 1
```

Now you go through each element of the array, its value is stored in line. The print line calls our countervariable, adds a blankspace, puts the line from the file. .rstrip() cuts some crap like newlines.

NOTE: This one is build on my opion how your file could look like. You should post what your file contains "exactly".

Tanks to @Guy his proposal makes the code more simple and understandable:

```
with (open('test', 'r')) as data:
    for counter,val in enumerate(data):
        print (str(counter) + ' ' + val.rstrip())
```

Comment: Can you use enumerate with files? for i, line in enumerate(data) to tidy up the counter. Not a major thing, admittedly..

Comment: @Guy Sure you can: 

with (open('test', 'r')) as data:
    for counter,val in enumerate(data):
        print (str(counter) + ' ' + val.rstrip())

Answer (score 0):

To just print the line number:

```
with open('victory.txt') as f_input:
    for index, row in enumerate(f_input):
        print('{} {}'.format(index, row), end='')
```

---

If you want to make changes to the existing file, you need to do it in two stages, i.e. read it in, close file, write out the updated values, for example:

```
with open('victory.txt') as f_input:
    data = f_input.read().splitlines()

with open('victory.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for index, row in enumerate(data):
        f_output.write('{} {}\n'.format(index, row))
```

Assuming that your input file is:

```
Jenny
Carlos
Matty
Anna
```

You will get an updated output file:

```
0 Jenny
1 Carlos
2 Matty
3 Anna
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) is used to give you a counter for each line. If you wish to start the counter from `1` you could add `start=1`.

`end=''` is used as each line read in from the file will already contain a trailing newline. Using `print()` also adds a newline, so with you need to remove the trailing newline or stop Python adding one when printing.